# What is meant by `&` and `#` in shell/bash coding? Please decode the line of Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to bash programming. I am trying to understand the following code.

I know only that `$` is used to pass the parameters.

```
function check_data () {
  local pattern=$1 iterations=$2 tck=$3 tdi=$4 tdo=$5
  ...
}

pattern="0110011101001101101000010111001001"

pins=(2 3 4 17 27 22)

# tck, tdi, and tdo are integer number

checkdatret=$(check_data $pattern $((2*${#pattern})) ${pins[$tck]} ${pins[$tdi]} ${pins[$tdo]})
```

Please, can you write the flow of execution steps of the last line of code?

Comment: I see binary! If that's the case then the '&'s mean the "operator bitwise and" which is true(1) if and only if both bits are true(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will see how the `$`,`#` works, and then answer the question.

**Part 1**

`${#pattern}` will give the length of the string that `pattern` holds. 
Therefore, in your above example

```
user@host:~$ echo ${#pattern}
34
```

since 34 is the length of the string `0110011101001101101000010111001001`.

**Part 2**

`${pins[$tck]}` is used to get the value at index `tck` of array `pins`. If the variable is not set, then it will default to 0. Here, since `tck` is not set,
`${pins[$tck]}` is equivalent to `${pins[0]}`. Thus the output will be:

```
user@host:~$ echo ${pins[$tck]}
2
```

The output will be 2 since array indexing starts at 0 in bash.

**Part 3**

`$()` is used for command substitution in bash. The command inside `()` will be executed and the output will be substituted.

**Original question**

`$((2*${#pattern}))` evalutes to `$((2*34))` which evalutes to `68`

Since `tck`,`tdi` and `tdo` are not set, it will default to 0. 
Therefore,

`${pins[$tck]}` evaluates to `${pins[0]}` which evalutes to `2`, the first element in the `pins` array.

Similarly, `${pins[$tdi]}` and `${pins[$tdo]}` both evalutes to 2

Therefore the final line in your script is now,

```
checkdatret=$(check_data 0110011101001101101000010111001001 68 2 2 2)
```

Now the function will be called with parameters

```
$1=0110011101001101101000010111001001
$2=68
$3=2
$4=2
$5=2
```

You need to `echo` the result from `check_data` function which will be substituted as

`checkdatret=YOUR_RESULT_FROM_FUNC`

Answer (score 1):

Try to analyze the code step by step by inserting some output commands

```
echo $pattern
echo ${#pattern}
echo $((2*${#pattern}))
echo $tck
echo ${pins[$tck]}
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what you're using as input to the script or the whole thing it's quite difficult to give an accurate description.

However:

```
# Var = how many characters in the variable
${#pattern} # 34 characters
echo ${#pattern}
34
```

I don't see any `"&"`'s in your code?

`check_data` is a function call, and everything else are arguments provided to `check_data`

```
# This is an array and $tck is supposed to represent a "Key"
${pins[$tck]}
# You can list keys with ${pins[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste your code into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

```
function check_data () {
  local pattern=$1 iterations=$2 tck=$3 tdi=$4 tdo=$5
  ...
}
```

Don't use both `function` and `()`. Prefer the `()`.

```
check_data() {
  local pattern=$1 iterations=$2 tck=$3 tdi=$4 tdo=$5
  ...
}
```

`local` defines the variables in the function as scoped to that function. `$1` and such are the values of the positional parameters the function receives.

```
pattern="0110011101001101101000010111001001"
```

That's just a simple string.

```
pins=(2 3 4 17 27 22)
```

This assigned the listed integers as values in a standard array. `${pins[0]` is 2, `${pins[1]` is 3, and so on to a `${pins[5]` of 22.

```
checkdatret=$(...)
```

Executes a subshell and assigns the stdout from it to `$checkdatret`.

```
check_data val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
```

Executes the function, passign the evaluated value of each argument, so -

```
check_data $pattern $((2*${#pattern})) ${pins[$tck]} ${pins[$tdi]} ${pins[$tdo]}
```

passes in `0110011101001101101000010111001001` (the value of the global variable `$pattern`) into the function as $1, which gets assigned to the local variable `$pattern`.

`$2` gets 68 to assign into `iterations`, because `${#pattern}` is the length of `$pattern`, which is 34; `$(( ... ))` gets replaces with the arithmetic evaluation of its content, which is `2*${#pattern}`.

I must assume `tck`, `tdi`, and `tdo` also have global versions, as the local ones inside the function would be unavailable here. I must also assume that each has a value in the range of 0-5, as each is used as an index to reference one of the six values in `pins`.

It would likely help to see the rest of the code and know what it is you actually need.